# How do you project a generic list into a dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Is there a simple, LINQ-only way to project a generic collection into a Dictionary, something which would eliminate the foreach in the following code block:

```
    Dictionary<int, Player> _rankedPlayers = new Dictionary<int,Player>();
    List<Player> rankedPlayers = Player.GetPlayers(Globals.FOOString, seasonCode);
    int i = 1;
    foreach (Player targetPlayer in rankedPlayers)
    {
      _rankedPlayers.Add(i, targetPlayer);
    }
```

Comment: I suppose you wanted to increment `i` on each insert, right?

Comment: I sure do Paul, forgot about the increment.

Comment: Than you change the code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the overload method of `Enumerable.Select` that produces an index of the element and project it into a dictionary using `Enumerable.ToDictionary`:

```
var rankedPlayers = Player.GetPlayers(Globals.FOOString, seasonCode)
    .Select((item, index) => Tuple.Create(item, index))
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Item1 + 1, item => i.Item2);
```

If your player list is too long, you might not feel comfortable creating a lot of `Tuple` instances and use an external index:

```
var i = 0;
var rankedPlayers = Player.GetPlayers(Globals.FOOString, seasonCode)
    .ToDictionary(i => ++i, item => item.Item2);
```

Although this approach creates a new class for the closure over `i`.

If this is still too much for you, you can create your own extension:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<int, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, TSource>();
        var i = 0;
        foreach(var item in source)
        {
            dictionary.Add(++i, item);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

But if you're using it only once, I would do it just like you did.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
var _rankedPlayers = Player.GetPlayers(Globals.FOOString, seasonCode)
      .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
      .ToDictionary(x => index, x => x.item);
```

Comment: You are creating an unnecessary type when you could have used `KeyVakuePair<int, Player>` or `Tuple<int, Player>`.